# Does git-flow merging scale well for larger teams?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

We're considering to adopt git-flow in a team of ~10 developers with weekly release schedule. Our plan is to branch a release branch from develop every monday and stabilize it by next monday's release to production. In the meantime, multiple features can land in develop and so it will most likely be necessary to resolve merge conflicts between develop and release branch.

Since the person doing the merge cannot possibly know all of the codebase and resolve conflicts by themselves, I'm wondering if this is going to cause problems. Basically, that person will need to talk to each of the developers and have them help resolve the conflict. I'm afraid this can be a bottleneck and become pretty tedious and painful.

Is this a problem in practice? Any experiences merging branches in git-flow style of work? Or some other branching strategies with similar benefits?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up the git workflow and the actual roles of the different people. git-flow doesn't make any assumptions on who does what, it merely sets guidelines on how branches should evolve. Who does what is entirely up to you, there is not necessarily a single person doing all the merges.

Comment: Yeah, it can be more people who rotate doing it, but the problem is still there. One person is responsible for merging the stable branch with all the new work that has arrived to develop that particular week. I can see that being a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have been a principle developer on an internal fork of git-flow within the company I work for and instrumental in rolling it out to a team of about 40 developers and we have seen some issues with it's implementation on a 3 week release cycle which can include several projects + bug fixes at once.

In general the git-flow workflow works really well but whenever you have hardening being carried out on the release branch whilst active development is being carried out on 'develop', there is always potential for merge conflicts to arise.

One way to alleviate this is to continually pull the release branch back into develop (have a CI or CRON task to handle this, it doesn't have to be manual).

There is always a level of human interaction required when bug fixing on the release branch. If you don't want to be pulling the release branch back continually (we don't), then you have to consider which bugs you are going to fix on release and which you will fix on develop ahead of the next release.

Either way, as long as your releases are planned carefully and you manage how and when you're going to fix particular bugs then you shouldn't run into too many merge conflicts.